# Convert Xpath to generic for all links

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to extract data from [this link](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/news?p=AAPL). I have written the code below by inspecting the path of the elements I wanted. But this gives a specific path for 1 news article. How do I get a generic path so I can extract multiple news articles without having to change the path each time?

```
import requests
from datetime import datetime
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/news?p=AAPL")
links=[]
date=[]
for i in range(20):
       driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, 250)")
       time.sleep(1)

all_items = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="latestQuoteNewsStream-0-Stream"]/ul/li[1]')
for item in all_items:
    links.append(item.find_element_by_xpath('./div/div/div[2]/h3/a[@href]').text)
    date.append(item.find_element_by_xpath('./div/div/div[2]/div[2]/span[2]').text)
    time.sleep(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

> How do I get a generic path so I can extract multiple news articles
> without having to change the path each time?

The generic path for these news articles would be something like this:

```
all_items = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(@class, 'js-content-viewer')]")
```

Here, we are grabbing all 'a' tag elements with the class containing 'js-content-viewer'.

When browsing the site, this seems to be a universal class to target which is shared on all news articles. Does this help answer your question? I believe you are asking for a selector which would work on other pages than the AAPL page for scraping news article info.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to get all articles and then iterate over them.

```
all_items = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="latestQuoteNewsStream-0-Stream"]/ul/li')
for item in all_items:
    try:
        links.append(item.find_element_by_xpath('.//h3/a').get_attribute('href'))
        date.append(item.find_element_by_xpath('.//span[contains(text(), "hours")  or contains(text(), "ago")]').text)
    except:
        pass
```

Its just a rough answer. Here I've used try-except block because there are Ads that cause errors. You can define your own conditions to check if an li tag is Ad or not.

Answer (score 0):

Few things you should be taking care while doing automation in Selenium.

1. Launch browser in full screen mode.
2. Use Explicit waits.
3. Always let Selenium sees the element, you may have to scroll to elements.
4. You can have generic xpath by removing `li[1]` and replacing with `li`
5. Few article does not have date in them, so we are using try-except to get rid off them.
6. It's a dynamic webpage, (scroll more new content will be shown), I have kept a limit in my code  `number_of_article_to_be_scrapped = 50` you can increase that to your desired number.

**Sample code :**

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.maximize_window()
#driver.implicitly_wait(30)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 50)
driver.get("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/news?p=AAPL")

links=[]
date=[]

first_ele = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("li.js-stream-content")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", first_ele)


number_of_article_to_be_scrapped = 50
j = 1
for i in range(number_of_article_to_be_scrapped):
    all_items = driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"//*[@id='latestQuoteNewsStream-0-Stream']/ul/li[{j}]")
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", all_items)
    print(all_items.find_element_by_xpath('.//descendant::a').get_attribute('href'))
    links.append(all_items.find_element_by_xpath('.//descendant::a').get_attribute('href'))
    try:
        print(all_items.find_element_by_xpath('.//descendant::i/following-sibling::span').text)
        date.append(all_items.find_element_by_xpath('.//descendant::i/following-sibling::span').text)
    except:
        date.append("NA")
        pass
    j = j + 1
    time.sleep(2)

print(links, date)
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

**Output :**

```
https://finance.yahoo.com/video/emmy-award-ratings-surprise-upside-205130601.html
10 hours ago
https://beap.gemini.yahoo.com/mbclk?bv=1.0.0&es=eiSxPhwGIS9SgwPrRfumd5wpg5Pdst0mnxsU_pU90PRd1qXot436mOSvU0GFNktUUDbBvcMpLH09FgnCOjT9Q3XUbEB9p5ljjKcsbJqFKwW7UG7HtWxgMOjJ1iT4KDsUntXFQFywy2NdwT7rnsDFOq.9_FXCoIoSxWha1mhQRuL8yQcthMSUmD13f3cHdyK2rg9ttPuyBXrwahfypRiwo8qkfGQ4AVcU4dnsKTdYomKjpSGKwLU7mAHauyxUnKfV7Ufo9RpxYmxLXbf3IbkElpFuAz6TUBbnwyWDbucbCJzGH7NUhKylPUKaCZQOVGVrf0igTnuGHSxcG79dpJ94_wtregffI2G2A6hZPurudjIyinaFAJpw4V1yFhx19pG7rCnTzLVDti3uJyIVrAeu.KteVFDSk46W1zO8BQsXJ1Nf__wBVbh_dhQTLut6jvtfVynVOpHgjlb193vn2VCs4uYlNGR_eWxcD.YpxIaK5RishaIMDX3l6fiRrll1xTCSpE_S_0x6kVBaVoe.S5MHFt0dsKrTF.RLRIkYrAIFcYgG_c2I7KMnJgjlMkBksth744pjZR423Buff33BuK.DYJhgMMIAD_ri15wuU4b7WnUbSfF8i4VDgZwwG0oNVrbOPCNRsbb1vyv4WoOKBmaK2U5gPz3Drlbg3zjAAvorBKZON.3FRVZjqjpU
https://finance.yahoo.com/video/sears-closes-final-store-netflix-142652445.html
17 hours ago
https://finance.yahoo.com/news/texas-startups-mount-fight-against-183349217.html
6 hours ago
https://finance.yahoo.com/m/bd9f5b13-f0c5-3664-a60a-ef8d6aa61a26/why-apple-facebook-amazon-.html
9 hours ago
https://finance.yahoo.com/m/6f3c84d0-41a2-3a51-9847-3d38dfbfcefa/big-tech-stocks-tumbled-in.html
9 hours ago
https://beap.gemini.yahoo.com/mbclk?bv=1.0.0&es=0RHhqLYGIS.aszeZ04KArFSmQbAJXXuYUfUXeHmPZC2RRJoR2z_T6_Tpbu4E947l4FDFsfNpbN4pnTuMbiWJ7_ZgUxNxNU9m0dJseX37L0u_Obp0LGAlG6_51BGa6K9K2HiHGeF_A8cQeoDsJ.s1oZIRXGnnle5Urq78xIMy_oQf7xRbc9wMzM1TAyu.IHvXsY0hKYcKR6xb9xd.7zxEpPO2x0ekroJAVf9n_xdDCYgka9DX1jmXrLdOUBbVDNNWDW0jwtnrYlLsU0HH2gRPgKjnYSP22_uCyQ6Xav8zfWQL9MowlvPOTJ0Cy4z2zfmVMCLIrNCviklRakm1loGybrKqqvQ_4_lPnAYaic82kZGXwKOS3c53DbJacbHqYIcVd3MCNwpNi7bB9l0jxqM743NNmWe_FN9e._isEkYEXxL1yQYYfaiyJ8gkXGQ1L2utfBhbRYpG2m0Hrc94tyPnxlhL0IbsPij3_otbjqrRcVFIoJ62gEAK.54JwpNc8t_egbpS7LsmgW1jlSMtCBv7sOUSE0eHLIi75hcLqswjSufIHdJoKW7FtXL0Iss1HTOHWMKKMbcuvyaRyQTweMQl97fULxPuAQPzLHUpXnj8fk0ppqN0BPLnDt6.PGUlHUXss6a1d_r2E44QwaebUhAlFVMpHIZLw6gtTA8NDGfeAzxTwuu.1DYElqxWFcfgwz6axjpWVdp9qGK.D6kU3wSMXRsE.bArAkg1m1kb8TzI
https://finance.yahoo.com/news/megacap-tech-selloff-hits-600-192932507.html
11 hours ago
https://finance.yahoo.com/news/facebook-alphabet-poised-bigger-fines-203629027.html
11 hours ago
https://finance.yahoo.com/news/top-analyst-reports-apple-thermo-194407872.html
11 hours ago
https://finance.yahoo.com/m/5ef84f5b-6102-38f6-965f-ba169eb31a2b/here-s-why-apple-s-iphone-13.html
12 hours ago
https://beap.gemini.yahoo.com/mbclk?bv=1.0.0&es=NvBwec0GIS9sEXVKZZGvkN8GnvmApw8a2W2R7h0N6k2noapnGpG3EuuCWWS7p5wCweiUyTH5zEWpvIvfItlcm1CIK2p4bvbl6CwSybNxwgS4EAcajpegQZbT4jH.nm9GMv.J0EVMEZEtvmKuUXETeAbPfssbS8_cCvkjUmJcy0pOI4LD0cBRyRjD93PizlaMpC6zfu18Q63JvdD2efXdnWjQC2rFRj5S_U27DpUEz6g771DhyYFnM8MnUf.UTxrqTvXaPOGAqTcDN9HXLufG.9AdsH5VMINQImUH532qRP0fD7oj1syIpmnHvDgJbXD7LzjZKjQNISkfQVD4oRCXPU9HdxPSuwRT2cSFj4Bqixww4OfhGDvZRVpzH4WalJFJffZjasg4zCccwv4lci4YuaNUfNqzgv50WsJhoTkFsZvvhpd.CtfzbqYoIVrNq2lGmdJOQ9gNtnJFxTutuF_lKAPC9zHqbCrJJ1RkCR05vez_PEUWRAA1b0K.3.4mLz7tuLZ6habZl08hxa24J8A36BSm7xvSOK5b49dJzdiYrnSuL1LWSL.LkuKBbu9fx7MFd7j978tF55P0_4vvAt1q._EykNkgiL9dqakVrPBlEA8n0PtNSIdFT71Nm80mMipA4qjr.bXk25dyCA1wip4PxFJ9vSxYNmot84_AoPB8Rc9AcLt7SrbJcBhrwZKxNfPpALH8sA--
https://finance.yahoo.com/m/65b53896-faf4-3a06-9d0d-a63cf3c83192/6-dow-jones-stocks-to-buy-and.html
13 hours ago
https://finance.yahoo.com/news/netflix-breaks-emmys-night-streaming-034958825.html
14 hours ago
https://finance.yahoo.com/video/ios-15-top-10-tips-170616151.html
14 hours ago
https://finance.yahoo.com/m/03c557e7-26f8-35dd-a6fe-f870a871c6e9/apple-iphone-13-setup-looks.html
15 hours ago
https://beap.gemini.yahoo.com/mbclk?bv=1.0.0&es=MwRR2cMGIS8hufuvYau6ZU2PYJWs.k29Bp2E6YPmQcdD29gAmIQOiKQ9mWf1sr.zJpcZmFlhMjD.L5U4E.MWEoONvvhisfMnyAYHagw.maOGd2kDoktc24uWUSbomvf0vaIF.Ee_17CMzdIghqZOywXRRH0ydNeOHjiabt6umaoIeFxs6BL6nURcAf8KOoXTrfnwVUY1KSgn5eT8dSUJiUMIIA03HfbAsmIgUDXvSyBSNOc95rQ9NrsYK.95s20gsSiLHz95gXhMNyx7zGH3Ep3AXbfR4UxuN2yrJ2TBr_TGcEI_g9Ty2oA6DwwjjTsHO.EiP2_B7oap07oDJFA5GY6zsQFS9jzwjetR.EX0lTCyB8ivpgE8sFfmMI_vXkMUslCdNl9eB8TgzIyRB8Ad6H5DQD9Pb34MlE6gz5PnO3jay_rboywYIeQxGY3R1psEqPdCRPsYuNJOt3nGi3KoFMWOE2UlcK_n4RZ7guCk4.q1w3MCFRGwBs2Z3F5NSiOO1BPTcWryotpiMH_Jii73qJEsStkJvqI2Ip_9qKAeROsjoVTgQ_XlEeeVWe8nPyffvf6SxBUuToELGfn84DcFM9dyoLuLTaacXRGsnzxozMNoE6J1SiZE
https://finance.yahoo.com/m/38552aae-d10a-34f8-9dcd-e50a60b893ac/evaluating-apple-aapl-after.html
17 hours ago
https://finance.yahoo.com/news/apples-aapl-comedy-series-ted-142202476.html
17 hours ago
https://finance.yahoo.com/news/apples-epic-loss-could-game-141023398.html
17 hours ago
https://finance.yahoo.com/m/5f3a5aa4-d20d-3ad7-8459-e1ba1ac7efa2/dow-jones-plunges-550-points.html
17 hours ago
https://beap.gemini.yahoo.com/mbclk?bv=1.0.0&es=F730htAGIS_EShK0CwiA70bpZR6FYQSnc1nCjDo2situ13qHG5jCXgbBdzG0FfkIta6.8.z.tur4QAaTie2JASTQNT19Q.pEwHeAXGed_G8uPbEOyOUv18OzkItAy4.4hNro8KezCQ4s7vrI2tHDUCqyp6WdsiUHPO4hi5.__J2N8Kws.TkZSajUhJg_dP8bqCJXbPipyksgTwjfObeUIBssqYwsrbnT6C6eiQxq2_NI3jidfrhywOCaFT56_wyOwsNCSaDNhHlfnngophAwMuz_KLxFh6.EoKwKuTOYwcARgNQ1BLD5vl3HFct5.AQ92DjuV8upMaNrjxQuXaHEccgooh6XuAjBos.gVLTSzfMzc8jAQje2zgSmo8P710vCT2anxXRjVDGdUCP2DKM5U7FU67VRW3i2BzRcmUEFlwtAjbURmYq2as1ApPYPghjWPtYaVGaQ.djtgW_Ppx.9pWfJNZ785BRO.N0tPmO5EUIOni8I1k5oq5QC14dS9atsW6CLDFQ-
https://finance.yahoo.com/m/f2241f0d-c113-3156-bad4-4a9bbf6b0de3/3-stocks-that-could-double.html
18 hours ago
https://finance.yahoo.com/news/analysts-upgrading-10-stocks-131452070.html
18 hours ago
https://finance.yahoo.com/news/10-trending-technology-stocks-reddit-130812830.html
18 hours ago
https://finance.yahoo.com/m/8dd2b2b8-d71d-3952-882a-950202f97759/2-bargain-stocks-to-buy-and.html
19 hours ago
https://beap.gemini.yahoo.com/mbclk?bv=1.0.0&es=sy80u3kGIS8HKaocYZHJbYPAoc45IldYlM8345PHhDZhFAfUPG2VHejc73twhmuQIcGoaZL_TOmyJthOMJk7nYp9XtW5mwcf0rYEF4s0UI_BcRSQwLunzKE8VHQzBeH4wLn0M4bGDvemCxquwny17OpTfGas5WbkYvxAV9xqHKRz6jbttBS5vAZwdPse.LmGaDoWg..bob5GCgcijpdMXU0tv1UMwsNdbKUcyKnhEEq0PAxjRgJMbkdHzt6.mh08P21lQFzTPw6MqLmoWzzF6pa6CxzNgwTNjPO5d0ELzJlLJOm4iL_FxyVYgDBJ3pi1FzhzGtxOajQA3JLeR.N7DXlPfEbA1i.NOStwNgEHxOOzF5Jz6sB.Ul8gu4pb9grBI0nH3.tm9AqASzhJ.LYHhSTe7oEi6SAus4Ylb1TzQq_liE7jwfsli8GNUP4_MeaSfXptuD4HqNnjX0ABEL4NPPHnckXi.SUY9pUALHigjdqBCcwFmnb3dBEdtplt6362dvqm5P9gOY0DnMRxu8XjIypuNpR0OGQduA9uUy3zuRJWz6__Szf_6gqJ40j9DVqDCuvPZQ0WcbkkBTi4ouxeVhRk4KAWNDoxfVVglLp4LRXRT3ZVJnNykuketnu2dWqMqpAuCHWmrG9mYAYrG1TPZac5ePH9FiKIrkrm93AEzOBwNa73kxuIDFuwKAztsqHcNOSnxDuEv.V4uN6REL.XT0fNLhttGC.wRrxqSzBH89pPvjSmRc5R0EC9r1OBPn_r8A--
https://finance.yahoo.com/m/64bcb782-2cca-37ec-8549-2ca10fd8fc93/dow-jones-futures-dive-on.html
19 hours ago
https://finance.yahoo.com/m/693d5293-fdc4-3a7a-8ac2-8954ff07569b/-buy-now-pay-later-consumer.html
19 hours ago
https://finance.yahoo.com/news/septembers-weakness-provides-good-entry-103510276.html
21 hours ago
https://finance.yahoo.com/m/8ef6837e-c32c-31e2-8257-c8dbb6ffbbb0/85-of-warren-buffett-s.html
21 hours ago
https://beap.gemini.yahoo.com/mbclk?bv=1.0.0&es=aWfeN8YGIS_JAq3LT0GoCgTl3GDYJ5rIK859daU_nuPf2XIJ2S3fJb3QkgUJ5LO2eoiZUowASU9bI8hxXVtXk_cFXJ03l3d7_Wx4UAcOlQZM7TfaM5AQV.mD0Yv0SrVzQrvoQbUGZiPyieoVDrE1rPYf3PlgmPOmIFR_bHnW_zewtN3PFB9sK2ysoF6VuT2AVvyRBFzNgdwyKpm4ZI7vdbG43MvDD3ZEomt0L5KGwYe4fV9sIxktm8AffNgZD4lBGUvSNJX0TqxmxTJKXWLpGHkVU_OEweOrmRTrOqwuMclVfujs.YFW54W51sClCQ8U4tqCDDFSRA5fEpFMovJ3B3TTGS5v6NZMCC0Ic9L_RhNRY4p7Bly.7LRLlwq6ZSboHaIjew0XUUbbAV9gBAw9DVb9ReH2hc4PSMU2S76z8nZnAyZ5K9IpcUM9B7UAcEz3pvdSkG_GEJ9p16mMH4nSIhYEeTkhx3SJ5UsDk3ogZfBes5qtBgQwdiVgfrLq3q_BJQFqzD.t1txGGVVqyMaOpZnzCTL7bBPaRzzSxAAQ8nj9M2B7YhZ4698NCgM5Uj5rMbKaeJjhPlg5sK5.CzX4Yf2G4A4-
https://finance.yahoo.com/news/apple-joins-streaming-elite-netflix-045412246.html
yesterday
https://finance.yahoo.com/news/apple-ted-lasso-snags-two-002517772.html
yesterday
https://finance.yahoo.com/news/apples-ios-15-releases-monday-163912972.html
2 days ago
https://finance.yahoo.com/news/youth-involved-in-the-stock-market-is-here-to-stay-teenage-investor-161706893.html
2 days ago
https://beap.gemini.yahoo.com/mbclk?bv=1.0.0&es=zGlaeZ4GIS8x7vFHwec8zh7SFw0TFjRuFMG_19.Xh_LbGbnFqwcBGb7CZhZcHguU996x3MhwiVI81URh42k2SbFZa9ZiaMB0Hp4gVlCUW2xBfCUztHcWhad0EM6cpX1PctfRgcgyDToS5WpzFAYzkMguKCH6mvALDy7PpXkXmNdE5pJ1j5DZYf1XmNJXtgFW7KMTqxzgacSV_Dsj9xFQ7zxbOmB8D5XDbIurc_z8S2zkJSTHvQq_HM36ZL8NGuDbgxmQQYOMYVBL.ZGGjMO54M79nFIFGo95BHJEexulf9UKmUHINUhjfvKk10SlM26GoGIspSMJyMdORebcbbOl35Se5ppVUpoq2QjUdNJMWVbxN9ngoEppq146C_ztWvF34IsnSE1NjEnlhlUqkYGu7YJy8AE18nC0dQwmGi.5DNQ.0OkxPwPAOFv8jQ9F3B0V_gLgKDqbddHxI8z9pmRTlVKPTZHosR5_Tnnpg.Mz5yqOvQinDB5aBceynsOyegRGDOfSLnc7gB7wmD8l35EuE4lCcL.UTAE3e.1qMLO8Y_.7Nzh.heDRXSHmIAo3sbnERo5EUCqd6mgtShqCA9QhHFjc6qjoYqSQKScPAo0vxodrKD.C5VnY3ZScBos5EK1bkNsT9oW6nsPmAo._danXPEmA76C5PHaPv6qINNqGIpg7zH1aBFGa86RkYjlh_dA2tHnceaV9DerU4NCGXQPVOdYnYbPpl7I5zb3RAupUDKisuFuSe1YFQERumygR1WB0q.J1.gf0_37swHeRkn3y4bhni5ONTmHF4pc5H4.q47DNRH7OUUsBYLxxBiMjb5d3hkfRIGjQWkfUGMKYMb9wMWPUyce9.27rxCnVbGOd8OnX9hWlmBd8nT8vJqI3tMiLZjJ8B15YDwNSTWHhXIdKs_kKbiHC.LcyGhcYTsxf0AqngBXipmz0n_YaU4Gw_tkU_pvmdDiNoAeQNJNBa6yW3k.HbixAQq0b38Hxp9RKEuBwnObzX3OfkTQrqK9TsAHn_Vh1WM5K3wp679HSJ.cGfInp.j_8EURQEUq5a8oHjcQhLsdQIBNnwGi.jS92BPKWmxtuPvYisw77mGFvLTRCQ2PqxtcnMv6ZXerMh5NMbTasHa1gJif.25Yw0byrjpgn.Iehsij02jB_5UfbmHY.Sq58isevP.wJ5gMPokXpMq_iyJdegP1cJ11bpFQXtjpwwBLqx3er1G8IILZoMycW3OBx48AKPq7XIy3vbQHYScOCTWsVz1aqgfrW7OylR.HibSDF9d6zwpZtHaI-
https://finance.yahoo.com/m/e058c25a-dd35-32b9-98d4-d2e31024f744/apple-and-the-innovator-s.html
2 days ago
https://finance.yahoo.com/m/80fcd29b-b396-3978-9ff8-200a6be47e6d/adding-500-to-these-top.html
2 days ago
https://finance.yahoo.com/m/2917a9d3-9087-3c92-8679-275468053b14/this-exciting-ipo-stock-has-a.html
2 days ago
https://finance.yahoo.com/news/1-navalny-allies-accuse-youtube-205855423.html
2 days ago
https://beap.gemini.yahoo.com/mbclk?bv=1.0.0&es=mVBYoc4GIS_Qq4M9W_EwtxIz1BzjZmYTvLaUUFf9bgQqU89MLyfFW6iT.trnlKCaaYoi_YE1qpGk1F25z75QAKeYhdaNMGOYw40K9_lTNvog86Vx90BYd9P8D.XWFPqREDUyVlb8tOP9RdfUDKxNpXRrMaWd2.RxNEpKmJDw0n91oBlW4vI_AdjWmaWIPwVF2YWdJ_lzbwJl4z96AxUkJad8cYzSOWriFtSKnQavye1bCqFaBGealOO_.KMs5JssUv8bo0hZkkCqN3W6IFPtk.UsqssJwqos9Bm4fNduZvHCP7pX9x73hegZFw1eGUkzTkjUCcXvVTaz0q_99ALMxTOLBh7fMNmyl.Tqnba5rC72LFNBkp0mN3v.PyDR22jsJgfWXosNgtJ0ZhuDXBO7mPM53pSsaIZwF1SEuw2I14lTBubHTpcj0jZbmz2Cu3xD9GOp8FvR4e8HYV6wQYkJXwM1RVcuM.9rSPMBP7ldX0EhNSiVe45HwbeVUHG9vyvHm46ZMMEqHnOJQ_eU59O2FX4TeeF0N9pE78z1MupZ_7gNxIcXa1K8ZLCveFnG2NAfP9JNmesg3pnhHthkx77wy3XO4JGMxNf_axMfv7jkvxSd8k83l40HBzcKiWzuKEdui6qRcHAhyFDzEihSxi.DFfRgfLEd2J1sxs22uPLHqA_.rzRF0V2Fd79lqYtYXY9mtGjNEDGpmHVvbM8HZ0VVNimg.sdK3_l_.Q_IMl09OpsOX7bPG5htGn28L.hqLQ--
https://finance.yahoo.com/m/538902b7-12e6-3fb2-be3d-8d633f108899/parus-files-second-patent.html
2 days ago
https://finance.yahoo.com/news/2021-emmys-its-ted-lasso-vs-mare-queens-gambit-in-streaming-showdown-134326879.html
3 days ago
https://finance.yahoo.com/m/df06f67f-ac8a-3ee5-8c71-fe16caeb09f9/ftc-biden-antitrust.html
3 days ago
https://finance.yahoo.com/m/1546aa8b-9464-3acb-ad3b-2bf055382838/a-goldman-etf-targets-a.html
3 days ago
https://beap.gemini.yahoo.com/mbclk?bv=1.0.0&es=70XvEXIGIS9mvgVTtvVMQUfHOSv6afBXF_Fh5JiTixXHtvNFKKvBDmOFfTr5LZ0sTt_ejbBP8TWykidrHRcTP5DgHxXMc93aqiAfJcHRAqK4YRjcqN4N.HCVabTua6r3p8fbV1w01V8bPuODeNV1u5mshtW5YBx1W.JieZtFib0ENxLwFW_4unSV8u.9VlVAfMgDBsZhaXfxMl2TjJzX.NFWxETEtXuaCaZhvIaEkOdtvUzMIcPX00mJGLR2GlT8UIcA70gplASjzjKtL9Gw4ArVUb592JQ7Mencbxe0JgKF1Swm9E_6Cf7q7Jc23bS_iwcs5GYoyPz7iY7IUTl0aTDqQ6XcDirY.JQyADAP6RXKOwfAQJ.GKep4Q8JXyABInB9d0TaXX3irm240_W9DExb7jkz2h.z_MeDXREwodMIEHbldfJI_Br2HWQxwnMA3yuehEkNkVuP0CMwOfCmtsUDy8.Zf6BOw5zb6h.q8xhYOi3.wad0Fx2CKMjnTXTTFsHML1nxDgdJLlzSgrHSirXNqCZsNbOigWPqDbcPeu5LYBkGGIC00KBUFo4CrKnrCMZ3kOkGZjLLnaKPHoy.Nz56K62V1uqP6JYUcJFIJb0w8EwqogJdTunonOsGrv_saT1tzA7w6i3welUJ8xBoXW2.JHsUccOwruBNAY4VehYQCDFKkQeGfxHSski4ZyJ3uA6YtaCB0t1tLtp7xXzsGDuSlvUURIRpoVsbTgrpabtL3hYswxH5kaqYib_L8BuhiZQE2qvksJma486eUigfKOZRixzMiC12ZrBEkASZaNDI7w8Ect0kheJbn
https://finance.yahoo.com/news/7-warren-buffett-quotes-know-200000130.html
3 days ago
https://finance.yahoo.com/m/3d56b93e-1dc1-3417-85c9-8f116559fe96/why-apple-stock-slipped-today.html
3 days ago
https://finance.yahoo.com/m/8d4d0b1e-04bf-3e39-b06d-a2d8c9cd2b74/dow-jones-dips-as-white-house.html
3 days ago
['https://finance.yahoo.com/video/emmy-award-ratings-surprise-upside-205130601.html', 'https://beap.gemini.yahoo.com/mbclk?bv=1.0.0&es=eiSxPhwGIS9SgwPrRfumd5wpg5Pdst0mnxsU_pU90PRd1qXot436mOSvU0GFNktUUDbBvcMpLH09FgnCOjT9Q3XUbEB9p5ljjKcsbJqFKwW7UG7HtWxgMOjJ1iT4KDsUntXFQFywy2NdwT7rnsDFOq.9_FXCoIoSxWha1mhQRuL8yQcthMSUmD13f3cHdyK2rg9ttPuyBXrwahfypRiwo8qkfGQ4AVcU4dnsKTdYomKjpSGKwLU7mAHauyxUnKfV7Ufo9RpxYmxLXbf3IbkElpFuAz6TUBbnwyWDbucbCJzGH7NUhKylPUKaCZQOVGVrf0igTnuGHSxcG79dpJ94_wtregffI2G2A6hZPurudjIyinaFAJpw4V1yFhx19pG7rCnTzLVDti3uJyIVrAeu.KteVFDSk46W1zO8BQsXJ1Nf__wBVbh_dhQTLut6jvtfVynVOpHgjlb193vn2VCs4uYlNGR_eWxcD.YpxIaK5RishaIMDX3l6fiRrll1xTCSpE_S_0x6kVBaVoe.S5MHFt0dsKrTF.RLRIkYrAIFcYgG_c2I7KMnJgjlMkBksth744pjZR423Buff33BuK.DYJhgMMIAD_ri15wuU4b7WnUbSfF8i4VDgZwwG0oNVrbOPCNRsbb1vyv4WoOKBmaK2U5gPz3Drlbg3zjAAvorBKZON.3FRVZjqjpU', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/video/sears-closes-final-store-netflix-142652445.html', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/news/texas-startups-mount-fight-against-183349217.html', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/m/bd9f5b13-f0c5-3664-a60a-ef8d6aa61a26/why-apple-facebook-amazon-.html', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/m/6f3c84d0-41a2-3a51-9847-3d38dfbfcefa/big-tech-stocks-tumbled-in.html', 'https://beap.gemini.yahoo.com/mbclk?bv=1.0.0&es=0RHhqLYGIS.aszeZ04KArFSmQbAJXXuYUfUXeHmPZC2RRJoR2z_T6_Tpbu4E947l4FDFsfNpbN4pnTuMbiWJ7_ZgUxNxNU9m0dJseX37L0u_Obp0LGAlG6_51BGa6K9K2HiHGeF_A8cQeoDsJ.s1oZIRXGnnle5Urq78xIMy_oQf7xRbc9wMzM1TAyu.IHvXsY0hKYcKR6xb9xd.7zxEpPO2x0ekroJAVf9n_xdDCYgka9DX1jmXrLdOUBbVDNNWDW0jwtnrYlLsU0HH2gRPgKjnYSP22_uCyQ6Xav8zfWQL9MowlvPOTJ0Cy4z2zfmVMCLIrNCviklRakm1loGybrKqqvQ_4_lPnAYaic82kZGXwKOS3c53DbJacbHqYIcVd3MCNwpNi7bB9l0jxqM743NNmWe_FN9e._isEkYEXxL1yQYYfaiyJ8gkXGQ1L2utfBhbRYpG2m0Hrc94tyPnxlhL0IbsPij3_otbjqrRcVFIoJ62gEAK.54JwpNc8t_egbpS7LsmgW1jlSMtCBv7sOUSE0eHLIi75hcLqswjSufIHdJoKW7FtXL0Iss1HTOHWMKKMbcuvyaRyQTweMQl97fULxPuAQPzLHUpXnj8fk0ppqN0BPLnDt6.PGUlHUXss6a1d_r2E44QwaebUhAlFVMpHIZLw6gtTA8NDGfeAzxTwuu.1DYElqxWFcfgwz6axjpWVdp9qGK.D6kU3wSMXRsE.bArAkg1m1kb8TzI', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/news/megacap-tech-selloff-hits-600-192932507.html', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/news/facebook-alphabet-poised-bigger-fines-203629027.html', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/news/top-analyst-reports-apple-thermo-194407872.html', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/m/5ef84f5b-6102-38f6-965f-ba169eb31a2b/here-s-why-apple-s-iphone-13.html', 'https://beap.gemini.yahoo.com/mbclk?bv=1.0.0&es=NvBwec0GIS9sEXVKZZGvkN8GnvmApw8a2W2R7h0N6k2noapnGpG3EuuCWWS7p5wCweiUyTH5zEWpvIvfItlcm1CIK2p4bvbl6CwSybNxwgS4EAcajpegQZbT4jH.nm9GMv.J0EVMEZEtvmKuUXETeAbPfssbS8_cCvkjUmJcy0pOI4LD0cBRyRjD93PizlaMpC6zfu18Q63JvdD2efXdnWjQC2rFRj5S_U27DpUEz6g771DhyYFnM8MnUf.UTxrqTvXaPOGAqTcDN9HXLufG.9AdsH5VMINQImUH532qRP0fD7oj1syIpmnHvDgJbXD7LzjZKjQNISkfQVD4oRCXPU9HdxPSuwRT2cSFj4Bqixww4OfhGDvZRVpzH4WalJFJffZjasg4zCccwv4lci4YuaNUfNqzgv50WsJhoTkFsZvvhpd.CtfzbqYoIVrNq2lGmdJOQ9gNtnJFxTutuF_lKAPC9zHqbCrJJ1RkCR05vez_PEUWRAA1b0K.3.4mLz7tuLZ6habZl08hxa24J8A36BSm7xvSOK5b49dJzdiYrnSuL1LWSL.LkuKBbu9fx7MFd7j978tF55P0_4vvAt1q._EykNkgiL9dqakVrPBlEA8n0PtNSIdFT71Nm80mMipA4qjr.bXk25dyCA1wip4PxFJ9vSxYNmot84_AoPB8Rc9AcLt7SrbJcBhrwZKxNfPpALH8sA--', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/m/65b53896-faf4-3a06-9d0d-a63cf3c83192/6-dow-jones-stocks-to-buy-and.html', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/news/netflix-breaks-emmys-night-streaming-034958825.html', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/video/ios-15-top-10-tips-170616151.html', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/m/03c557e7-26f8-35dd-a6fe-f870a871c6e9/apple-iphone-13-setup-looks.html', 'https://beap.gemini.yahoo.com/mbclk?bv=1.0.0&es=MwRR2cMGIS8hufuvYau6ZU2PYJWs.k29Bp2E6YPmQcdD29gAmIQOiKQ9mWf1sr.zJpcZmFlhMjD.L5U4E.MWEoONvvhisfMnyAYHagw.maOGd2kDoktc24uWUSbomvf0vaIF.Ee_17CMzdIghqZOywXRRH0ydNeOHjiabt6umaoIeFxs6BL6nURcAf8KOoXTrfnwVUY1KSgn5eT8dSUJiUMIIA03HfbAsmIgUDXvSyBSNOc95rQ9NrsYK.95s20gsSiLHz95gXhMNyx7zGH3Ep3AXbfR4UxuN2yrJ2TBr_TGcEI_g9Ty2oA6DwwjjTsHO.EiP2_B7oap07oDJFA5GY6zsQFS9jzwjetR.EX0lTCyB8ivpgE8sFfmMI_vXkMUslCdNl9eB8TgzIyRB8Ad6H5DQD9Pb34MlE6gz5PnO3jay_rboywYIeQxGY3R1psEqPdCRPsYuNJOt3nGi3KoFMWOE2UlcK_n4RZ7guCk4.q1w3MCFRGwBs2Z3F5NSiOO1BPTcWryotpiMH_Jii73qJEsStkJvqI2Ip_9qKAeROsjoVTgQ_XlEeeVWe8nPyffvf6SxBUuToELGfn84DcFM9dyoLuLTaacXRGsnzxozMNoE6J1SiZE', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/m/38552aae-d10a-34f8-9dcd-e50a60b893ac/evaluating-apple-aapl-after.html', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/news/apples-aapl-comedy-series-ted-142202476.html', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/news/apples-epic-loss-could-game-141023398.html', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/m/5f3a5aa4-d20d-3ad7-8459-e1ba1ac7efa2/dow-jones-plunges-550-points.html', 'https://beap.gemini.yahoo.com/mbclk?bv=1.0.0&es=F730htAGIS_EShK0CwiA70bpZR6FYQSnc1nCjDo2situ13qHG5jCXgbBdzG0FfkIta6.8.z.tur4QAaTie2JASTQNT19Q.pEwHeAXGed_G8uPbEOyOUv18OzkItAy4.4hNro8KezCQ4s7vrI2tHDUCqyp6WdsiUHPO4hi5.__J2N8Kws.TkZSajUhJg_dP8bqCJXbPipyksgTwjfObeUIBssqYwsrbnT6C6eiQxq2_NI3jidfrhywOCaFT56_wyOwsNCSaDNhHlfnngophAwMuz_KLxFh6.EoKwKuTOYwcARgNQ1BLD5vl3HFct5.AQ92DjuV8upMaNrjxQuXaHEccgooh6XuAjBos.gVLTSzfMzc8jAQje2zgSmo8P710vCT2anxXRjVDGdUCP2DKM5U7FU67VRW3i2BzRcmUEFlwtAjbURmYq2as1ApPYPghjWPtYaVGaQ.djtgW_Ppx.9pWfJNZ785BRO.N0tPmO5EUIOni8I1k5oq5QC14dS9atsW6CLDFQ-', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/m/f2241f0d-c113-3156-bad4-4a9bbf6b0de3/3-stocks-that-could-double.html', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/news/analysts-upgrading-10-stocks-131452070.html', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/news/10-trending-technology-stocks-reddit-130812830.html', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/m/8dd2b2b8-d71d-3952-882a-950202f97759/2-bargain-stocks-to-buy-and.html', 'https://beap.gemini.yahoo.com/mbclk?bv=1.0.0&es=sy80u3kGIS8HKaocYZHJbYPAoc45IldYlM8345PHhDZhFAfUPG2VHejc73twhmuQIcGoaZL_TOmyJthOMJk7nYp9XtW5mwcf0rYEF4s0UI_BcRSQwLunzKE8VHQzBeH4wLn0M4bGDvemCxquwny17OpTfGas5WbkYvxAV9xqHKRz6jbttBS5vAZwdPse.LmGaDoWg..bob5GCgcijpdMXU0tv1UMwsNdbKUcyKnhEEq0PAxjRgJMbkdHzt6.mh08P21lQFzTPw6MqLmoWzzF6pa6CxzNgwTNjPO5d0ELzJlLJOm4iL_FxyVYgDBJ3pi1FzhzGtxOajQA3JLeR.N7DXlPfEbA1i.NOStwNgEHxOOzF5Jz6sB.Ul8gu4pb9grBI0nH3.tm9AqASzhJ.LYHhSTe7oEi6SAus4Ylb1TzQq_liE7jwfsli8GNUP4_MeaSfXptuD4HqNnjX0ABEL4NPPHnckXi.SUY9pUALHigjdqBCcwFmnb3dBEdtplt6362dvqm5P9gOY0DnMRxu8XjIypuNpR0OGQduA9uUy3zuRJWz6__Szf_6gqJ40j9DVqDCuvPZQ0WcbkkBTi4ouxeVhRk4KAWNDoxfVVglLp4LRXRT3ZVJnNykuketnu2dWqMqpAuCHWmrG9mYAYrG1TPZac5ePH9FiKIrkrm93AEzOBwNa73kxuIDFuwKAztsqHcNOSnxDuEv.V4uN6REL.XT0fNLhttGC.wRrxqSzBH89pPvjSmRc5R0EC9r1OBPn_r8A--', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/m/64bcb782-2cca-37ec-8549-2ca10fd8fc93/dow-jones-futures-dive-on.html', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/m/693d5293-fdc4-3a7a-8ac2-8954ff07569b/-buy-now-pay-later-consumer.html', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/news/septembers-weakness-provides-good-entry-103510276.html', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/m/8ef6837e-c32c-31e2-8257-c8dbb6ffbbb0/85-of-warren-buffett-s.html', 'https://beap.gemini.yahoo.com/mbclk?bv=1.0.0&es=aWfeN8YGIS_JAq3LT0GoCgTl3GDYJ5rIK859daU_nuPf2XIJ2S3fJb3QkgUJ5LO2eoiZUowASU9bI8hxXVtXk_cFXJ03l3d7_Wx4UAcOlQZM7TfaM5AQV.mD0Yv0SrVzQrvoQbUGZiPyieoVDrE1rPYf3PlgmPOmIFR_bHnW_zewtN3PFB9sK2ysoF6VuT2AVvyRBFzNgdwyKpm4ZI7vdbG43MvDD3ZEomt0L5KGwYe4fV9sIxktm8AffNgZD4lBGUvSNJX0TqxmxTJKXWLpGHkVU_OEweOrmRTrOqwuMclVfujs.YFW54W51sClCQ8U4tqCDDFSRA5fEpFMovJ3B3TTGS5v6NZMCC0Ic9L_RhNRY4p7Bly.7LRLlwq6ZSboHaIjew0XUUbbAV9gBAw9DVb9ReH2hc4PSMU2S76z8nZnAyZ5K9IpcUM9B7UAcEz3pvdSkG_GEJ9p16mMH4nSIhYEeTkhx3SJ5UsDk3ogZfBes5qtBgQwdiVgfrLq3q_BJQFqzD.t1txGGVVqyMaOpZnzCTL7bBPaRzzSxAAQ8nj9M2B7YhZ4698NCgM5Uj5rMbKaeJjhPlg5sK5.CzX4Yf2G4A4-', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/news/apple-joins-streaming-elite-netflix-045412246.html', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/news/apple-ted-lasso-snags-two-002517772.html', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/news/apples-ios-15-releases-monday-163912972.html', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/news/youth-involved-in-the-stock-market-is-here-to-stay-teenage-investor-161706893.html', 'https://beap.gemini.yahoo.com/mbclk?bv=1.0.0&es=zGlaeZ4GIS8x7vFHwec8zh7SFw0TFjRuFMG_19.Xh_LbGbnFqwcBGb7CZhZcHguU996x3MhwiVI81URh42k2SbFZa9ZiaMB0Hp4gVlCUW2xBfCUztHcWhad0EM6cpX1PctfRgcgyDToS5WpzFAYzkMguKCH6mvALDy7PpXkXmNdE5pJ1j5DZYf1XmNJXtgFW7KMTqxzgacSV_Dsj9xFQ7zxbOmB8D5XDbIurc_z8S2zkJSTHvQq_HM36ZL8NGuDbgxmQQYOMYVBL.ZGGjMO54M79nFIFGo95BHJEexulf9UKmUHINUhjfvKk10SlM26GoGIspSMJyMdORebcbbOl35Se5ppVUpoq2QjUdNJMWVbxN9ngoEppq146C_ztWvF34IsnSE1NjEnlhlUqkYGu7YJy8AE18nC0dQwmGi.5DNQ.0OkxPwPAOFv8jQ9F3B0V_gLgKDqbddHxI8z9pmRTlVKPTZHosR5_Tnnpg.Mz5yqOvQinDB5aBceynsOyegRGDOfSLnc7gB7wmD8l35EuE4lCcL.UTAE3e.1qMLO8Y_.7Nzh.heDRXSHmIAo3sbnERo5EUCqd6mgtShqCA9QhHFjc6qjoYqSQKScPAo0vxodrKD.C5VnY3ZScBos5EK1bkNsT9oW6nsPmAo._danXPEmA76C5PHaPv6qINNqGIpg7zH1aBFGa86RkYjlh_dA2tHnceaV9DerU4NCGXQPVOdYnYbPpl7I5zb3RAupUDKisuFuSe1YFQERumygR1WB0q.J1.gf0_37swHeRkn3y4bhni5ONTmHF4pc5H4.q47DNRH7OUUsBYLxxBiMjb5d3hkfRIGjQWkfUGMKYMb9wMWPUyce9.27rxCnVbGOd8OnX9hWlmBd8nT8vJqI3tMiLZjJ8B15YDwNSTWHhXIdKs_kKbiHC.LcyGhcYTsxf0AqngBXipmz0n_YaU4Gw_tkU_pvmdDiNoAeQNJNBa6yW3k.HbixAQq0b38Hxp9RKEuBwnObzX3OfkTQrqK9TsAHn_Vh1WM5K3wp679HSJ.cGfInp.j_8EURQEUq5a8oHjcQhLsdQIBNnwGi.jS92BPKWmxtuPvYisw77mGFvLTRCQ2PqxtcnMv6ZXerMh5NMbTasHa1gJif.25Yw0byrjpgn.Iehsij02jB_5UfbmHY.Sq58isevP.wJ5gMPokXpMq_iyJdegP1cJ11bpFQXtjpwwBLqx3er1G8IILZoMycW3OBx48AKPq7XIy3vbQHYScOCTWsVz1aqgfrW7OylR.HibSDF9d6zwpZtHaI-', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/m/e058c25a-dd35-32b9-98d4-d2e31024f744/apple-and-the-innovator-s.html', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/m/80fcd29b-b396-3978-9ff8-200a6be47e6d/adding-500-to-these-top.html', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/m/2917a9d3-9087-3c92-8679-275468053b14/this-exciting-ipo-stock-has-a.html', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/news/1-navalny-allies-accuse-youtube-205855423.html', 'https://beap.gemini.yahoo.com/mbclk?bv=1.0.0&es=mVBYoc4GIS_Qq4M9W_EwtxIz1BzjZmYTvLaUUFf9bgQqU89MLyfFW6iT.trnlKCaaYoi_YE1qpGk1F25z75QAKeYhdaNMGOYw40K9_lTNvog86Vx90BYd9P8D.XWFPqREDUyVlb8tOP9RdfUDKxNpXRrMaWd2.RxNEpKmJDw0n91oBlW4vI_AdjWmaWIPwVF2YWdJ_lzbwJl4z96AxUkJad8cYzSOWriFtSKnQavye1bCqFaBGealOO_.KMs5JssUv8bo0hZkkCqN3W6IFPtk.UsqssJwqos9Bm4fNduZvHCP7pX9x73hegZFw1eGUkzTkjUCcXvVTaz0q_99ALMxTOLBh7fMNmyl.Tqnba5rC72LFNBkp0mN3v.PyDR22jsJgfWXosNgtJ0ZhuDXBO7mPM53pSsaIZwF1SEuw2I14lTBubHTpcj0jZbmz2Cu3xD9GOp8FvR4e8HYV6wQYkJXwM1RVcuM.9rSPMBP7ldX0EhNSiVe45HwbeVUHG9vyvHm46ZMMEqHnOJQ_eU59O2FX4TeeF0N9pE78z1MupZ_7gNxIcXa1K8ZLCveFnG2NAfP9JNmesg3pnhHthkx77wy3XO4JGMxNf_axMfv7jkvxSd8k83l40HBzcKiWzuKEdui6qRcHAhyFDzEihSxi.DFfRgfLEd2J1sxs22uPLHqA_.rzRF0V2Fd79lqYtYXY9mtGjNEDGpmHVvbM8HZ0VVNimg.sdK3_l_.Q_IMl09OpsOX7bPG5htGn28L.hqLQ--', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/m/538902b7-12e6-3fb2-be3d-8d633f108899/parus-files-second-patent.html', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/news/2021-emmys-its-ted-lasso-vs-mare-queens-gambit-in-streaming-showdown-134326879.html', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/m/df06f67f-ac8a-3ee5-8c71-fe16caeb09f9/ftc-biden-antitrust.html', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/m/1546aa8b-9464-3acb-ad3b-2bf055382838/a-goldman-etf-targets-a.html', 'https://beap.gemini.yahoo.com/mbclk?bv=1.0.0&es=70XvEXIGIS9mvgVTtvVMQUfHOSv6afBXF_Fh5JiTixXHtvNFKKvBDmOFfTr5LZ0sTt_ejbBP8TWykidrHRcTP5DgHxXMc93aqiAfJcHRAqK4YRjcqN4N.HCVabTua6r3p8fbV1w01V8bPuODeNV1u5mshtW5YBx1W.JieZtFib0ENxLwFW_4unSV8u.9VlVAfMgDBsZhaXfxMl2TjJzX.NFWxETEtXuaCaZhvIaEkOdtvUzMIcPX00mJGLR2GlT8UIcA70gplASjzjKtL9Gw4ArVUb592JQ7Mencbxe0JgKF1Swm9E_6Cf7q7Jc23bS_iwcs5GYoyPz7iY7IUTl0aTDqQ6XcDirY.JQyADAP6RXKOwfAQJ.GKep4Q8JXyABInB9d0TaXX3irm240_W9DExb7jkz2h.z_MeDXREwodMIEHbldfJI_Br2HWQxwnMA3yuehEkNkVuP0CMwOfCmtsUDy8.Zf6BOw5zb6h.q8xhYOi3.wad0Fx2CKMjnTXTTFsHML1nxDgdJLlzSgrHSirXNqCZsNbOigWPqDbcPeu5LYBkGGIC00KBUFo4CrKnrCMZ3kOkGZjLLnaKPHoy.Nz56K62V1uqP6JYUcJFIJb0w8EwqogJdTunonOsGrv_saT1tzA7w6i3welUJ8xBoXW2.JHsUccOwruBNAY4VehYQCDFKkQeGfxHSski4ZyJ3uA6YtaCB0t1tLtp7xXzsGDuSlvUURIRpoVsbTgrpabtL3hYswxH5kaqYib_L8BuhiZQE2qvksJma486eUigfKOZRixzMiC12ZrBEkASZaNDI7w8Ect0kheJbn', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/news/7-warren-buffett-quotes-know-200000130.html', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/m/3d56b93e-1dc1-3417-85c9-8f116559fe96/why-apple-stock-slipped-today.html', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/m/8d4d0b1e-04bf-3e39-b06d-a2d8c9cd2b74/dow-jones-dips-as-white-house.html'] ['10 hours ago', 'NA', '17 hours ago', '6 hours ago', '9 hours ago', '9 hours ago', 'NA', '11 hours ago', '11 hours ago', '11 hours ago', '12 hours ago', 'NA', '13 hours ago', '14 hours ago', '14 hours ago', '15 hours ago', 'NA', '17 hours ago', '17 hours ago', '17 hours ago', '17 hours ago', 'NA', '18 hours ago', '18 hours ago', '18 hours ago', '19 hours ago', 'NA', '19 hours ago', '19 hours ago', '21 hours ago', '21 hours ago', 'NA', 'yesterday', 'yesterday', '2 days ago', '2 days ago', 'NA', '2 days ago', '2 days ago', '2 days ago', '2 days ago', 'NA', '2 days ago', '3 days ago', '3 days ago', '3 days ago', 'NA', '3 days ago', '3 days ago', '3 days ago']
```

Comment: Can we have some update on this post ?